# Create a custom ISO Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: server, system-installation, 22.04, iso

I am trying to create a custom **Ubuntu 22.04** ISO image with some special features.

In older versions I was using a preseed to add those features, but since Ubuntu 20.04 the preseed has been outdated.

The aim of this ISO would be to add some custom folders to the ISO and copy them to the Ubuntu OS during the installation.

I have been researching and I have found articles like this: [create custom Ubuntu 22.04 live server iso](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404757/create-custom-ubuntu-22-04-live-server-iso)

But I have not found any clue for adding folders (and copy them later).

Is there any method to achieve this with **xorriso**? Or I would have to try with another method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use "autoinstall" Take your pick: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233454/how-to-preseed-ubuntu-20-04-desktop https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403686/ubuntu-22-04-autoinstall-method  https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall   and https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference

Comment: "The aim of this ISO would be to add some custom folders to the ISO and copy them to the Ubuntu OS during the installation." That you do by altering the ISO itself. See for instance the answers here https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd/49679#49679 (the method to add an "askubuntu"-link still works; change that to your directory setup you want to add in `/etc/skel`)

Comment: Hi @Dasel, have you found any resources for same. I am also trying to implement the same, not sure from where I start.